# I can't read beta sites' chat logos!

Tags: bug, chat, design, chat-transcript

Here, you try:
[image]
If it weren't for the text shadow, it might as well be entirely invisible...

The cause is a CSS rule lurking in the transcripts for beta sites only:

```
#transcript-logo {
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #273A5D;
}
```

The problem is the `#273A5D` - a bluish colour not dissimilar to that used for the site name in the beta theme. Disabling that rule yields the much more manageable
[image]
I'll admit it is a little hard to read the "beta" in that shot. But if you had to choose which part was readable, wouldn't you choose the bit that *tells you the name of the site*?

**Edit:** It happens when actually in a chat room too!

Comment: No, I prefer to know the site's in beta more than the actual name. It lets me know they haven't worked out that CSS bug yet.

Comment: I'd rather be able to see both!

Comment: Have you seen the top bar lately? Dark heavy blue on near black background is apparently the new thing. I actually like the lighter approach, but I think that we are in the minority here. Is everyone else coding in the dark? Hard to tell where this mindset originated. Soon we will be full circle back to the black background, green text foreground screens that everyone used to love. http://i.imgur.com/d557nCr.png

Comment: @TravisJ I mean, I quite like dark backgrounds. It's just that you need light foregrounds if it's going to work. And **+1** for green screens.

Comment: @TravisJ Dark backgrounds make coloured highlighting easier and focus the viewer on those coloured bits more than a bright site with some not-black-but-still-readable bits ;) (Bright backgrounds, on the other hand, make area colouring easier - subtle greyscale backgrounds etc.)

Comment: @FEichinger - The eye has a hard time discerning bright colors in a dark background. Using a dark background and bright foreground is more harmful than helpful. It may appear "modern", but it is really a detraction and slightly straining of the eye.

Comment: **To close voters:** The problem still very much exists and can still be reproduced by going to a beta site chat room. This question is *not* "no longer reproducible".

Answer (score 10):

I'd be happy with a light blue. After all it's the style the beta sites use anyway in their header:

[image: the code review beta site's header logo]

But possibly even better would be not having a dilemma by making the logo entirely dark blue on light blue, and entirely light blue on dark blue in the chat rooms.