# Why does the logo not show up when signing up for a site and confirming the account?

Tags: bug, beta-sites, favicon, sign-up

I was signing up for Software Recommendations and realized that a unicorn stole their logo! **We need to get it back!** Really, the logo is missing when you sign up on SR, <strike>and I don't know if this is a universal bug or just here. Also, I did get an error a few seconds later (it should be recorded), so it might be related to that.</strike> **Edit: It is on all *betas*; it isn't just my problem.**

[image]

Note to SE team: if needed I can give the URL that has problems... it should show things like what I was trying to sign up with/verification codes, etc. if you want that.

Comment: This is on all beta sites - not sure why.

Comment: @hichris Has it been documented before?

Comment: Not that I know of, just from personal experience.

Comment: How dare you blame unicorns! They are pure, innocent creatures!

Comment: @BlueIce I never said they were wrong in doing so! They had the right to do so! :) However, I think we should at least create another one...

Comment: Appears to be same bug [reported here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142201/beta-favicons-lost-their-letters-in-profile), was fixed for user profiles and site lists but not in that specific location. Good catch! :)

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/207968/178816

Comment: AFAICT, this issue no longer applies, since the site logo is no longer shown on the confirmation page at all.

Answer (score 5):

The recently released [Stack Overflow Unofficial Patch](https://stackapps.com/questions/4486/stack-overflow-unofficial-patch) v1.14 includes a client-side fix for this issue.  For the curious, here's the code that implements it:

```javascript
if ( !/^\/users\/(login|signup)\b/.test( location.pathname ) ) return;
$('img.site-logo[src="//cdn.sstatic.net/beta/img/apple-touch-icon.png"]').attr(
    'src', '//cdn.sstatic.net/' + location.hostname.split('.')[0] + '/img/icon-48.png'
);
```

(Yes, I'm aware that `location.hostname.split('.')[0]`would not yield the correct site name on per-site metas.  Fortunately, you can't actually log in on a per-site meta; if you try, you get redirected to the main site login page.)